# Logical operators, how are these evaluated?

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

I'm going through past papers to revise and there was a question that wasn't explained and I can't seem to find much online in regards to this question/topic.

**Binary values**
a = 00110011
b = 10101010

I'm not quite sure personally what the difference between & and && is, and the same with | and || - these are both a little confusing.

**Which of the following statements return a TRUE condition?** 
(a & b)  == 10111011
(a || b) == 10111011
(a ^ b) == 10111011
(a | b) == 10111011
(a && b) == 10111011

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The && and || are short-circuit operators. They will return true/false in the same way that & and | would. The difference is basically that the second expression only gets evaluated if necessary. There are also some usage differences (i.e. && can only operate on scalars).

See this link for explanation of short-circuit operators: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html

Comment: marvelous answer. simply marvelous!

Answer (score 1):

The & and | are bitwise operators which means they operate on a bit by bit manner. the && and || operators are logical operators which return a True/False answer. For example:

a = 00110011

b = 10101010

If you calculate (a & b) it will return 00100010

the == operator compares two statement to see if they are equal and returns a True/False value.

So (a & b) == 10111011 which means 00100010 == 10111011 is a False statement and returns False.

If you calculate (a && b) you have two values which are both True, because each value except 00000000 is True so (a && b) returns a True value and it is not a numerical value to be compared to another, so writing (a && b) == 10111011 does not have any meaning.

so is for || and | .

Comment: This question is tagged as matlab, not C/C++. This answer is wrong with respect to matlab.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking specifically for matlab. It will treat all non-0 values as true.

Consider: `7&3` = true, `7&8` = true - so different behavior than C

If you have a and b as binary numbers matlab will treat them both as true. result will be true or false - definetly not a number. So the result of your code will always be false.

Anyway as Matlab statements it will ALWAYS treat your numbers as decimal. Meaning `a^b` will be calculated as "a to the power of b".

---

I suppose you actuallcy consider bitwise. That is not present in Matlab - instead you need vectors of logicals.

In Matlab & and | are vectorized in the meaning they compare vecors elementwise. && and || compare just skalars and shortcircuit. ^ is the power operator - so you need to write it as xor. And for elementwise comparison you need the `eq` command instead of ==.
Last to assure all bits are the same there is the `all` command.

You would write it like this:

```
a = [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
b = [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]

all(eq(a & b, [1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]))
all(eq(xor(a,b), [1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]))
all(eq(a | b, [1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]))
```

This also means the statements with && and || are invalid in this case.